# NPM errors when trying to set up hardhat - Nodejs & NPM are installed

Tags: hardhat, npm

I am trying to install hardhat to follow a tutorial on testing. I got nodejs and npm installed (confirmed with commands node -v and npm -v which showed the versions for each) and then I ran npm init and set up a new project called hh-testing. Then I ran "npm install --save-dev hardhat and I got this massive list of errors (see img below).

How can I fix this? Do I need to install something relating to python?

[image: Here is my terminal with all the errors]

Comment: No nothing related to python. Can you try once in an empty directory? I've never seen this error.

Comment: A completely new directory where i haven't even run forge init yet?

Comment: forge init? Are you trying to use hardhat and foundry together?

Answer (score 0):

open the command prompt as an administrator, go to the folder path, and then try to install it.

Comment: How do I open the command prompt as administrator?

Answer (score 0):

You've mentioned that you've installed Node.js and npm, but it's important to ensure you're using a Node.js version that is compatible with the packages you're trying to install. Some older packages may require specific Node.js versions. You can check the compatibility by reviewing the documentation for [link](https://onlinecasinoslovenia.net/) or the specific tutorial you're following. I wanted to share some of my experiences and thoughts on online casinos. I've been exploring this world for a while now, and I think it's important to approach it with caution and responsibility.

Comment: I think I did do that...the tutorial that I was following told me to use 2.12.0 so I did